# Does doInit() event fire when the attribute values change in a lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a parent component which has a child component. The child component has an init action which basically sets the body of the child component. But this is in turn dependent on the child component attributes which reset based on the parent component attributes. SO my question here is the action I am calling on init needs to be called after all the child component attributes have been set correctly from the parent attribute. What is the best way of firing this action? Does attribute change re-trigger init action? If not I need to find a different way of setting the body.

Also, previously I was creating this child component dynamically after all the parent component attributes were reading. But again I needed to fire something on the parent component based on the click of a button inside the child. I couldn't make it happen since the event fired from my dynamically created child component was not being captured by the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could handle that value change in the controller by defining a 'change' handler, then the framework will do the rerender of the component.

You have more info [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_data_change.htm).